# php artisan migrate command error : Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

i am debian user

When I create a laravel project ( last version ) and run the `php artisan migrate` command , I'll face the following error :

With 5.4 version, I have no problem

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ticket and table_name = migrations)

  at /home/mostafa/W/laravel-projects/tickets/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
      /home/mostafa/W/laravel-projects/tickets/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  2   PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=ticket", "root", "21900", [])
      /home/mostafa/W/laravel-projects/tickets/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68

  Please use the argument -v to see more details.
```

I'm grateful for someone who can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but it might work if you try to change `DB_HOST` from `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`

Comment: Yeeeeees . Very Thanks